# Prevent deletion of blank lines when tangling code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, whitespace, tangle

The Python style guide asks for two blank lines surrounding class and function definitions ([see PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines)).
When those blank lines are added in Org-Mode source blocks, they are removed during tangling. How can prevent this behavior and keep my blank lines?

The setting `(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)` does not do the trick (for me).

This question is related to this one: [Org Mode Babel - ensure more than one empty line between tangled code blocks (for python)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31738/org-mode-babel-ensure-more-than-one-empty-line-between-tangled-code-blocks-fo).
In my case I would be fine with adding the blank lines myself and have them tangled as necessary part of the code unless this is bad style.